# How to use "apt-get install" via ssh cmd

Tags: apt

I am trying to use "apt-get" to install a software called "expect" via cmd with ssh:

`ssh -t root@111.111.111 'apt-get install -v -y expect'`

However, this is what I get:

```
apt 1.0.1ubuntu2 for amd64 compiled on Aug  1 2015 19:20:48
Supported modules:
*Ver: Standard .deb
*Pkg:  Debian dpkg interface (Priority 30)
 Pkg:  Debian APT solver interface (Priority -1000)
 S.L: 'deb' Standard Debian binary tree
 S.L: 'deb-src' Standard Debian source tree
 Idx: Debian Source Index
 Idx: Debian Package Index
 Idx: Debian Translation Index
 Idx: Debian dpkg status file
 Idx: EDSP scenario file
```

And the software is not installed.

My question is: can or can't we use apt-get via ssh like above?

** By the way, yes, I can normally log in via ssh and install the software via ssh. **

Comment: @roaima, The intention is not to automate login. It's just an experiment. By the way, I took off the login part from the question.

Comment: To be more accurate, search the web or your man pages about `ssh-agent` & `ssh-add`

Comment: @Gilles Quenot, I took off the login automation from the question.

Comment: You say, "I can normally log in via ssh and install the software via ssh.", but you didn't log in via ssh and install the software with the command `apt-get install -v -y expect`?

Comment: I am not aware of any common distribution that puts restrictions on commands depending on whether they are run locally or through ssh ... actually that would be pretty difficult to enforce. Therefore the answer is: "yes, you can use apt-get via ssh as shown above". You actually did it.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get) for `apt-get` the `-v` flag simply prints the version of `apt-get`. So no software will be installed.

Run this instead

```
ssh -t root@111.111.111 'apt-get install -y expect'
```

Comment: I promise I saw the "-v" meant "verbose; thank you!